# Необходимо посчитать количество элементов JSON с определенным значением?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

JSON:

```
x = {"order": {"id": 1, "statuscode": "SUCCESS_ENDED"},
    {"order": {"id": 2, "statuscode": "PROCESSING"},
    {"order": {"id": 3, "statuscode": "SUCCESS_ENDED"},
    {"order": {"id": 4, "statuscode": "SUCCESS_ENDED"}
```

Нужно через цикл вывести на print кол-во элементов, у которых statuscode: SUCCESS_ENDED

Comment: Приведите ваш вариант решения. Ссылка "Править" внизу вопроса

Comment: @Дмитрий если бы у автора был вариант решения, он и не стал бы задавать вопрос, не так ли?

Comment: @andreymal не так, накидать логику -> попробовать реализовать -> получить выходные данные -> проанализировать -> почитать ошибки -> спросить

Answer (score 1):

У вас переменная `x` "слегка" непонятна. На JSON она слаба похожа. Давайте наченем с того что приведем ее хоть к какому то типу данных, например вот так:

```py
x = [{"order": {"id": 1, "statuscode": "SUCCESS_ENDED"}},
    {"order": {"id": 2, "statuscode": "PROCESSING"}},
    {"order": {"id": 3, "statuscode": "SUCCESS_ENDED"}},
    {"order": {"id": 4, "statuscode": "SUCCESS_ENDED"}}]
```

Для `python` это тип данных `list`, что является итерируемым типом. В каждом элементе `list` лежит `order` со значениями. Давайте по ним пробежимся и посчитаем:

```py
>>> count = 0
>>> for i in x:
...   for order, value in i.items():
...     if value["statuscode"] == "SUCCESS_ENDED":
...       count+=1
... 
>>> count
3
```

И еще один вариант, если мы остаемся при своем и считаем, что переменная `x` такая какая есть, то ее хотя бы надо принять за строку:

```py
x = '''[{"order": {"id": 1, "statuscode": "SUCCESS_ENDED"},
    {"order": {"id": 2, "statuscode": "PROCESSING"}
    {"order": {"id": 3, "statuscode": "SUCCESS_ENDED"}
    {"order": {"id": 4, "statuscode": "SUCCESS_ENDED"}'''
```

и с помощью модуля `re` найти все совпадения с `SUCCESS_ENDED`

```py
>>> import re
>>> pattern = r"SUCCESS_ENDED"
>>> all_mathces= len(re.findall(pattern, x))
>>> all_mathces
3
```